# 0xD after saving a file in diff

Tags: linux, git, sublimetext, sublimetext3

```
-{/*}  
+{/*}^M
```

After saving a file I see in `git diff` ^M appended to the lines where trailing white spaces were removed because of `"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true`. But why is `^M` there?
I have checked with `default_line_ending` Sublime Text setting - it is set to system. I'm on Linux.

Comment: Where did you check the `default_line_ending` setting, perhaps projects .gitconfig overrides it ?

Comment: default_line_ending is Sublime Text setting.